# Adding validation to Django User form

Tags: django, python-3.x, monkeypatching, mezzanine

I'd like to customize the user sign-up form in Django/Mezzanine to allow only certain email addresses, so I tried to monkey-patch as follows:

```
# Monkey-patch Mezzanine's user email address check to allow only
# email addresses at @example.com.
from django.forms import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
from mezzanine.accounts.forms import ProfileForm
from copy import deepcopy
original_clean_email = deepcopy(ProfileForm.clean_email)
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    if not email.endswith('@example.com'):
        raise ValidationError(
            ugettext("Please enter a valid example.com email address"))
    return original_clean_email(self)
ProfileForm.clean_email = clean_email
```

This code is added at the top of one of my `models.py`.

However, when I runserver I get the dreaded

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

If I add

```
import django
django.setup()
```

then `python manage.py runserver` just hangs until I `^C`.

What should I be doing to add this functionality?

Comment: Out of interest, why did you think that adding `django.setup()` was a possible fix? It's meant for when your using Django in standalone scripts, you shouldn't ever use it in your `models.py`.

Comment: I know that now! I've used it in standalone scripts to set up the models I need and didn't realise that it wouldn't work within an actual Django project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `myapp/apps.py` for one of your apps (I've use `myapp` here), and define an app config class that does the monkeypatching in the `ready()` method.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        # do the imports and define clean_email here
        ProfileForm.clean_email = clean_email
```

Then use `'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'` instead of `'myapp'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
    ...
]
```

You might need to put Mezzanine above the app config for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, Alasdair. I found I needed to add `name = 'myapp'` to the `MyAppConfig` class definition. Can you provide a link to the relevant Django documentation or tutorial in your answer? It doesn't seem easy to find.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best place to link to. You might find the the docs for [django apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) helpful. In particular, the [`ready`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method is the appropriate place to register signals, and in your case, do the required monkeypatching.

Comment: I didn't realise that `name` was required, I've updated the answer.